# Why does $\frac{\log_{e}k}{k}$ approach $0$ as $k$ approaches $\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponentiation

A interesting problem: why is it that as $k$ approach infinity, $$\frac{\log_{e} k}{k}$$ approaches $0$?

Another problem: why $e^n=(1+n/x)^x$ as $x$ approach infinity?

Comment: Because polynomial growth is faster than logarithmic growth...

Comment: @The Chaz-is there any reference i could look at?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation , although I'm sure others have better resources!

Comment: For your second question: that depends on how you *define* the exponential $e$! One can *define* $e^n$ as that limit, in which case the answer is "by definition"; or one can define the exponential in a different way, in which case the equality would be derived. But without knowing how *you* define the exponential, it is impossible to give a good answer to your second question.

Comment: The logarithm (the base does not matter) grows slowly, as compared with other elementary (increasing) functions (notice also $\log(k)/\sqrt{k}$ tends to zero). Informally, the logarithm almost "always looses"; as, conversely, the exponential almost always wins.

Comment: The first question has already been dealt with here on MSE at this location: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial/55492#55492

Comment: @leonbloy s/looses/loses/g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you get the indeterminate form $\infty / \infty$ as $k\to\infty$, you can use l'Hopital's rule:

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\ln k}{k} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1/k}{1} = 0$$

Comment: Shouldn't the denominator be just 1? The way you have it there, it would be $-\infty$.

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I will edit to fix.

Answer (score 6):

**First.**

You can also understand it by graph.

[image]

let

$$f(k)=k,\ g(k)=\ln k$$

then

$$f'(k)=1,\ g'(k)=\frac{1}{k}$$

If $k>1$,

$$f'(k)>g'(k),\ \lim_{k\to \infty}f'(k)=1>\lim_{k\to \infty}g'(k)=0$$

notice that

$$f(1)>g(1)$$

so

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{g(k)}{f(k)}=0$$

**Second.**

notice that

$$e=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left (1+\frac{1}{x}\right )^x$$

if $1/n$ is constant, we know

$$e=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left (1+\frac{n}{x}\right )^{\frac{x}{n}}$$

so

$$e^n=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left (1+\frac{n}{x}\right )^x$$

**Important thing**

$$e=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left (1+\frac{\bigstar}{x}\right )^\frac{x}{\bigstar}$$

$$\frac{\bigstar}{x}\times\frac{x}{\bigstar}=1$$

Comment: +1 for using the graph and the use of Star as a variable.

Answer (score 4):

(For the first question.)

For any fixed $x > 0$, it follows from the binomial formula
$$
(1 + x)^k = {k \choose 0}x^0  + {k \choose 1}x^1  + {k \choose 2}x^2  +  \cdots  + {k \choose k-1}x^{k - 1}  + {k \choose k}x^k 
$$
that 
$$
(1 + x)^k  > \frac{{k(k - 1)}}{2}x^2  > k,
$$
for all $k$ greater than some positive integer $K$. Hence also
$$
\ln (1 + x)^k  > \ln k \;\; \forall k > K
$$
and, in turn,
$$
k \ln(1+x) > \ln k \;\; \forall k > K.
$$
Thus,
$$
0 < \frac{{\ln k}}{k} < \ln (1 + x) \;\; \forall k > K.
$$
Noting that $\varepsilon := \ln(1+x)$ is an arbitrary positive number, by definition of limit we have
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \frac{{\ln k}}{k} = 0.
$$

**EDIT:**

Noting that 
$$
\ln n^{1/n}  = \frac{{\ln n}}{n}, 
$$
any proof of
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } n^{1/n}  = 1
$$
can serve as a proof of
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{\ln n}}{n} = 0.
$$
[Here](http://puzzles.members.winisp.net/Mathematical/Solutions/LimitNto1byNSolution.htm) you can find an elegant proof of $\mathop {\lim }\nolimits_{n \to \infty } n^{1/n}  = 1$, using the [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Answer (score 3):

1. Application of [l'Hôpital's rule](http://L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s%20rule)
   $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\log k}{k}=\frac{\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty
   }\left( \frac{d}{dk}\log k\right) }{\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }\left( \frac{%
   dk}{dk}\right) }=\frac{\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{k}}{%
   \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }1}=\frac{0}{1}=0.$$
   Alternatively, if one changes variables, using the substitution recommended by Theo Buehler $k=e^l\rightarrow\infty $ as $l$ tends to $\infty$, the limit can be evaluated observing that for $k\ge 1$, $e^l\ge\dfrac{l^2}{2}$, one has  $$0\le\frac{\log k}{k}=\frac{l}{e^l}\le\frac{2l}{l^2}=\frac{2}{l}.$$ Applying limits one gets by the [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\log k}{k}=0$. However, I am not able to show the inequality without the Taylor series for the exponential (see Steven Stadnicki's comment).
2. By definition of $e=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+\frac{1}{k}%
   \right) ^{k}$

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+\frac{n}{x}\right) ^{x}
&=&\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+\frac{1}{\frac{x}{n}}\right) ^{x} \\
&=&\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{\frac{x}{n}}\right) ^{%
\frac{x}{n}}\right) ^{n} \\
&=&\left( \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+\frac{1}{\frac{x}{n}}\right) ^{%
\frac{x}{n}}\right) ^{n} \\
&=&(e)^{n}=e^{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: L'Hôpital seems a bit of an overkill for 1. I'd substitute $k = e^{l}$ and use that $e^{l} \geq l^2 / 2$, for example.

Comment: @Theo Buehler: Yes, it is. I will use your substitution.

Comment: Doesn't one still need to show the exponential inequality?  That's obvious if you know the Taylor series for the exponential, but the phrasing of the question seems to suggest that it's below that level...

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki: You are right. I am not able to show it without the Taylor series for the exponential.

Answer (score 3):

Another straightforward approach is through integrals.  Since $x^{-1} \lt x^{t-1}$ for any $t\gt 0$ and $x\gt 1$, $\int_1^k x^{-1}\mathrm{d}x\lt \int_1^k x^{t-1}\mathrm{d}x$; $\log(k)\lt {k^t-1\over t}$.  But choosing $t={1\over2}$ here gives $\log(k)\lt 2(k^{1/2}-1)$ and ${\log(k)\over k}\lt 2(k^{-1/2}-k^{-1})$, and the latter obviously goes to $0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.  Note that you can easily adapt this to show that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(\log k/ k^\epsilon) = 0$ for any $\epsilon\gt 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Every time $k$ gets multiplied by $e$, $\log_e k$ increases by $1$.  So $\frac{\log_e k}{k}$ is replaced by
$$
\frac{1+\log_e k}{ek}
$$
and this is less than half of $\frac{\log_e k}{k}$ when $k$ is bigger than....17, I think.

So every time $k$ gets multiplied by $e$, the expression gets cut down to less than half what it was before.  Hence it must approach 0.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, first note that $(1+n/x)^x = \exp(x \log(1+n/x))$.  Second, observe that the graph of the natural logarithm function $\log(x)$ is tangent to $x-1$ at $x=1$, so that $\log(1+\epsilon) = \epsilon + \mathcal O(\epsilon^2)$.  Thus

$$\left(1+\frac n x\right)^x = \exp\left(x \log\left(1+\frac n x\right)\right) = \exp\left(x\left(\frac n x + \mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {x^2}\right)\right)\right) = \exp\left(n + \mathcal O\left(\frac 1 x\right)\right),$$

which tends to $\exp(n)$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Not quite coincidentally, the approximation $\log(1+\epsilon) \approx \epsilon$ for $|\epsilon| \ll 1$ and the other techniques demonstrated above come handy in all sorts of calculations dealing with probabilities of unlikely events and their complements.  It's also useful to note that the approximation gives a strict upper bound: $\log(1+\epsilon) \le \epsilon$, and the equality only holds when $\epsilon = 0 $.